# (PHP) Reject descriptions that don't include the required tags

Tags: php

This is how my script currently sends errors when the description is too short:

```
if(strlen($linkres->content) = minStoryLength ) { // if  description is too short
        $main_smarty->assign('submit_error', 'incomplete');
        $main_smarty->display($the_template . '/submit_errors.tpl');
        $error = true;
    }
```

I want to send the same error message when the description does not include at least one of these tags/words:

```
<img><youtube><googlevideo><xoinks><break><vimeo><revver><myspace>
<veoh><wmv><dailymotion><ifilm><metacafe><tubeley><guba>
```

thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$tags = array('img','youtube','googlevideo','xoinks','break','vimeo','revver','myspace','veoh','wmv','dailymotion','ifilm','metacafe','tubeley','guba');

$contains = false;
foreach($tags as $check)
{
    if(preg_match("/<".$check.">/", $linkres->content))
    { 
        $contains = true;
    }
}

if(!$contains) 
{ 
   // here goes your error
}
```

This is an alternative to inti's solution.

Answer (score 1):

I would use some regex here, to do a negative match

```
$tags = array("img", "youtube", "googlevideo", "xoinks", "break", "vimeo", "revver", "myspace", "veoh", "wmv", "dailymotion", "ifilm", "metacafe", "tubeley", "guba");

if ((strlen($linkres->content) < minStoryLength) // if  description is too short
 || (!preg_match("'[<](".implode("|",$tags).")[^>]*[>]'is",$linkres->content)))
// or it does not contain any of the above
{ 
    $main_smarty->assign('submit_error', 'incomplete');
    $main_smarty->display($the_template . '/submit_errors.tpl');
    $error = true;
}
```

**EDIT:** made a little correction

**EDIT2:** I had a missing parameter for `preg_match`

Comment: Upvoted, but your constants (`minStoryLength`) should really be in uppercase for differentiation from other variables.

Comment: @rudi_visser you mean "my" constants or the asker's? I just used the code provided and added my solution.

Answer (score 0):

1 Insert your tags in an array

2 Iterate the array and check if the value is matching

```
foreach()
```

http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php

3 Show error